# Android Bluetooth pairing different behavior

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, pairing

I have developed an app that prints receipts to a Bluetooth printer (Star Micronics).

When I execute my app on an Android tablet with 4.1 OS everything works.

When I execute my app on an Android tablet with 4.0 OS I have to re enter Bluetooth pairing password every time I want to print and the printer failed to connect although it is paired.

Is this a bug of 4.0 or I have to do something in my code?

Comment: can you found any solution becuse same problem i am getting i have galaxy tab2 7" with version 4.0.4 it work well while client has galaxy tab2 7" with version 4.0.3 it's not working. if found any thing then pls help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have encountered the same problem! It's because of the version of Android. 
Update the version of Android to 4.1 will do the trick.
You can find lots of ways to update the Android version from 4.0 to 4.1 online.

Jake